# View gets pushed out of linear layout - android

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, mobile

Im facing issue, where imageview is getting pushed out by inner linear layout. The views are wrapped inside an outer linear layout. I tried a constraint layout chaining, but the view needed a constraint from left and right side, which resulted in aligning the view into the center, which is not desired. I want the view, to be aligned to the left side. Does anybody know?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--RIGHT ITEM-->
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/messagesdetails_wrapLayout_right"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:gravity="start"
            android:background="@drawable/messages_item_background">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/messagesdetails_textview_right"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/segoe_ui"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:text="Your text" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/messagesdetails_timestamp_right"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="start|bottom"
                    android:textSize="11dp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/segoe_ui"
                    android:textColor="#80FFFFFF"
                    android:text="Timestamp" />
        </androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/messagesdetails_copybutton_right"
            android:layout_width="28dp"
            android:layout_height="28dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:alpha="1"
            android:src="@drawable/copy_icon_messages_clicked" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To pin the view to the left in a constraint layout you can use the

```
app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0"
```

See [detailed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69604403/what-is-vertical-bias-or-horizontal-bias-used-for-in-androids-constraintla). That way you can have constraints with left and right but the view would stick to the left.